# Run stored procedure with cursor output in Sql Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

I have an sp from a package that look like this

```
PROCEDURE SEARCH_SOMETHING (
InParam          IN     VARCHAR2,
InParam2            IN     NUMBER,
OutCursor              OUT empcur)
```

How can I run this and see the data that the cursor retrieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can simply call the cursor in the begin end block. Or use the Execute statement.

```
DECLARE
    L_INPARAM VARCHAR2;
    L_INPARAM2 NUMBER;
    L_OUTPARAM empcur;
BEGIN
    L_INPARAM:= value;
    L_INPARAM2:= VALUE_NUMBER;
   SEARCH_SOMETHING (
          L_INPARAM,
          L_INPARAM2
          L_OUTPARAM);

for i in L_OUTPARAM 
 loop
   use values of i;
 END LOOP:
END;
```